# Mean and standard derivation

Tags: probability, statistics

A set of numbers consists of one's and three's. Find the mean and standard derivation if there are 23 one's and 17 three's.

What's the meaning of this question ? I know the formula for mean and s.d. But I don't understand the meaning of this question. Can someone explain it ? Thanks

Comment: The set contains (23+17) numbers, 23 of which are equal to 1 and the rest are equal to 3.

Comment: So the mean is 74/40 right ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Which formula for standard derivation formula should I use ?

Comment: There is only one standard deviation formula.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$. Sometimes, for theoritical reasons, we devide by $n-1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: No need to divide by $n - 1$ in this case, $n$ would suffice in the standard deviation formula.

Comment: @Augustin Isn't that "variance"? Its root must be taken to get the s.d..

Comment: Yes you're right. $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$. Never said it was a "need" to divide by $n-1$ here. It's just not entirely true that there is only one formula.

Comment: @Mathxx It is **[standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)** (not derivation).

Answer (score 0):

**Sample means and variances from data in frequency-Value format.**

If there are $K$ different values $v_j,$ each having frequency
$f_j,$ then the sample mean can be expressed as 
$$\bar X = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^K f_jv_j}{\sum_{j=1}^K f_j}
= \sum_{j=1}^K r_jv_j ,$$
where $n = \sum_{j=1}^K f_j$ and $r_j = f_j/n,$ for $j = 1,\dots,K.$

In this notation, the sample variance is
$$S^2 = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^K f_j(v_j - \bar X)^2}{n-1}.$$

In your case $K = 2,\;n=40;\;v_1=1,\;v_2 = 3$ and $f_1 = 23,\;f_2=17.$  Are such formulas useful for your purposes?

*Addendum:* Slight modifications of these formulas are sometimes
used to get estimates of $\bar X$ and $S$ from a histogram
in which the frequencies $f_j$ of the bins (intervals) can be determined
from the associated bar heights on the vertical scale. In this case, as an approximation,
all of the data in an interval are assumed to be located
at the bin midpoints $m_j$. Then the formulas above are used
with $m_j$ taking the place of the $v_j.$

Comment: Perhaps the 'meaning' of the question is to prompt you to see that the formulas for sample mean and variance in my Answer are equivalent to the formulas that consider the n observations individually. Not sure what you're asking. Please leave a Comment here if you need further explanation.